# How do I change the color or shape of the labels in ggraph?

Tags: r, ggraph

I am still new at coding and am having trouble with changing either the color or the shape of the labels in my ggraph. The nodes belong to two different groups and I would like to be able to see the difference between the two. Meaning 'Standard' is one color and 'Sector' another color. How do I do this?
Below I have attached my data, code and plot.

Data1

```
 Standard Sector                      weight
   <chr>    <chr>                        <int>
 1 Bonsucro "Advisory and consultancy "      1
 2 Bonsucro "Education & research"           2
 3 Bonsucro "Engineering "                   1
 4 Bonsucro "Envionmental / Nature NGO"      1
 5 Bonsucro "Farming"                        1
 6 Bonsucro "Processors"                     1
 7 ISCC     "Education & research"           2
 8 ISCC     "Energy "                        5
 9 ISCC     "Processors "                    1
10 RSB      "Aviation "                      2
# … with 19 more rows
```

Code

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width=12, fig.height=10)

library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)
library(ggraph)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

data <- read.csv("/Users/Anna/Desktop/Organizing Global Markets/Exam/R script and data/OGM data.csv", sep = ";")

View(data)

data1 <- data %>%
  group_by(Standard,Sector) %>%
  summarize(weight=n())

network <- graph_from_data_frame(data1,vertices=NULL)

ggraph(network, layout = "kk") +
  geom_node_point() +
  geom_edge_link(aes(edge_width=weight)) +
  geom_node_label(aes(label=name), repel = T)
```

Plot

[image: Plot]

Comment: Please share your data using `dput`?

Comment: Hi! The code you shared does produce an error? If not, please include the code that generates an error and the error message it produces.

Comment: @JuanBosco, No it does not produce an error. It is when I have tried to add something like color it produces an error.

Answer (score 1):

I only have that small bit of data, but here are some of the methods you can use to change label elements. I've labeled the parameters with comments.

```
ggraph(network, layout = "kk") +
  geom_node_point() +
  geom_edge_link(aes(edge_width=weight)) +
  geom_node_label(aes(label=name), repel = T, 
                  color = "white",          # text
                  fill = "#B21E29",         # label background
                  size = 4,                 # font size
                  label.r = unit(20, "pt"), # corner radius of label box
                  label.size = .1,          # label border size
                  label.padding = unit(1, "lines"))
```

[image]

I don't know of an easy way of grouping the fill using `ggraph`, but I've managed a blunt force kinda method...

Start with creating the `ggraph` object with a fill assigned to the labels. (It can be any color.) You will need the `grid` package for this to work.

```
library(grid)        # <- I'm new
library(ggraph)
library(igraph)
library(tidyverse)

g <- ggraph(network, layout = "kk") +
  geom_node_point() +
  geom_edge_link(aes(edge_width = weight)) +
  geom_node_label(aes(label = name), repel = T, 
                  color = "white",  # text
                  fill = "#B21E29", # label background
                  size = 4,         # font size
                  label.r = unit(20, "pt"), # corner radius label box
                  label.size = .1,          # label border size
                  label.padding = unit(1, "lines"))
```

Now establish how you will want to assign colors. I used `Standard` for assigning the colors here.

Then using the `grid` package, extract the data in the `ggraph` object.

```
dt2 <- data %>% 
  mutate(fill2 = ifelse(Standard == unique(data$Standard)[1],
                       "purple4",
                       ifelse(Standard == unique(data$Standard)[2],
                              "darkgreen",
                              ifelse(Standard == unique(data$Standard)[3],
                                     "darkblue",
                                     "transparent")))) %>% 
  select(-Standard, -weight)
```

When I validated this, I found that two sectors are used two times. In one, there is extra whitespace, so it's not a problem. The other will be a problem. There is only one label for each sector; it can't be assigned two colors.

```
nrow(dt2) # too many; there is a sector in two standards...
arrange(dt2, Sector) # looks like processors are okay; extra whitespace
# however, edu and research isn't 
dt2 <- dt2[-2, ] # remove one of the two duplicate labels
```

Now that we have established colors for the sectors, we need to add the standards and their colors to this new data frame, `dt2`.

```
y = data.frame(Sector = unique(data$Standard),
               fill2 = unique(dt2$fill))
dt2 <- rbind(dt2, y)
```

Next, the labels & colors need to be put in the same order as the `ggraph` object. When we get to that point, we are going to replace the fill colors in the graph.

At this point, I extracted the data from the `ggraph` object so that I could get this data in the right order. I used a joining to order them. Since I need to match fields with a join, I changed the name of the label field so it matches the `ggraph` object.

```
x <- ggplot_build(g)$data[[3]][, c(3, 6, 7)] # 3rd layer's data
#                        label colour    fill
# 1                   Bonsucro  white #B21E29
# 2                       ISCC  white #B21E29
# 3                        RSB  white #B21E29
# 4  Advisory and consultancy   white #B21E29
# 5       Education & research  white #B21E29
# 6               Engineering   white #B21E29
# 7  Envionmental / Nature NGO  white #B21E29
# 8                    Farming  white #B21E29
# 9                 Processors  white #B21E29
# 10                   Energy   white #B21E29
# 11               Processors   white #B21E29
# 12                 Aviation   white #B21E29 

names(dt2)[1] <- "label"

z = left_join(x, dt2) # new fill colors in the right order

str(z) # looks ok
```

Now, let's inject these ordered colors into the entire data frame in the object so it's easier to incorporate them into the object. Then build the graph, add the new data, and take a look.

```
# extract the entire data frame
g2 <- ggplot_build(g)$data[[3]]

g2$fill <- unlist(z$fill2, use.names = F) # inject new colors

# check it
g2$fill # looks okay

gg <- ggplot_build(g) # the entire graph object
gg$data[[3]] <- g2    # data with new fill
# graph it
grid.draw(ggplot_gtable(gg))
```

FYI, this change doesn't actually affect the `ggplot` object; it's a grid object that is impacted.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is very helpful. But I would like to have different colours for the sectors and the standards. So for example RSB, ISCC, Bonsucro, RSPO, RTRS to be one color and then the rest of them another color. So I can distinguish between the two groups.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution and all the effort you have put into it. But unfortunately, that is still not what I would like to do. I am not sure how to better explain what I want to do.